# Why does AsyncTask's THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR have a queue limit while SERIAL_EXECUTOR does not?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, executor

I'm curious if anyone has any insight as to why the Android platform `AsyncTask`'s built in `Executor`s don't both have a limit or aren't both unlimited in the number of queued `AsyncTask`s they can handle.

`THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` [initially](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/donut-release/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#L135) had a limit on its `LinkedBlockingQueue` of 10 in the early versions of Android. [Since KitKat](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#L194), it has a limit of 128.

`SERIAL_EXECUTOR`'s `ArrayDeque` has [never had a limit](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr0-release/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#L201), since it was introduced in Honeycomb as the default `AsyncTask` `Executor`.

`ArrayDeque`'s [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayDeque) doesn't provide a way to limit its capacity. But `LinkedBlockingQueue`'s [default constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#LinkedBlockingQueue()) would provide a default queue capacity limit of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2,147,483,647), essentially unlimited.

If anything, `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` would be more likely to get backed up with `Runnable` `AsyncTask`s, since they are unable to execute in parallel. But both are equally able to run out of memory if too many tasks are queued up before they can be executed. `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` just reaches its limit much sooner, throwing a `RejectedExecutionException` once its queue overflows the limit of 128, while `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` would continue to be able to add tasks until it ran out of memory.

I have a use case where I need to quickly queue up several hundred render tasks that need to run asynchronously. Using `AsyncTask`'s default `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` works just fine. But these render tasks can and ideally should run in parallel, as they have no shared state. If I change the code to use `AsyncTask`'s `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`, the app crashes with: `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@b4d342c rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@bcccef5[Running, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 53]`.

Is there any reason I wouldn't want to create my own `Executor`, mirroring `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` except without limiting its queue capacity?

Comment: IMHO, you should be considering whether `AsyncTask` is the correct solution, particularly when compared with more modern alternatives. If you wish to stick with `AsyncTask`, I do not recommend creating an unbounded queue, lest you run out of heap space. Creating an `Executor` with a *larger* queue may be reasonable, though.

Comment: I had used Kotlin Coroutines as my initial solution, but ran into a performance issue that I didn't take the time to work out, something with calling `GlobalScope.launch()` hundreds of times that introduced a delay. I'd like to still go this route, once I get more experience with Coroutines. In the interim, the easy route would be to leave the `AsyncTask` using the default `SERIAL_EXECUTOR`, as this does work fine. But I had this question about why the difference in queue capacity limit for the `Executor`s in the `AsyncTask` API? Why is it OK for one to be unlimited and the other not?

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are ill-suited for Stack Overflow. Usually only Developer X can make a definitive statement; everyone else can just offer opinions. It is fairly unlikely that Romain Guy or later maintainers of `AsyncTask` (the "Developer X" for your "Decision Y" question) are going to see this, let alone attempt to provide an answer. IMHO, neither should be unlimited. If I had to guess, it was a backwards compatibility move, as part of the changes to `AsyncTask` over the (gasp!) decade.

Comment: Fair enough. Someone still may have feedback as to why it seemed like a logical decision. For example, why would you prefer an `Executor` with a _larger_ queue, which would still potentially hit its limit and throw a `RejectedExecutionException` over an unbounded queue that eventually throws an `OutOfMemoryError`? Seems I'd prefer the latter, which would allow the app to execute for longer before it reached a real limit, rather than an arbitrary limit I had placed on it.

Comment: A `RejectedExecutionException`, in a single spot in your app, is orders of magnitude easier to cope with than an `OutOfMemoryError` that can occur at any spot in the app. At least with the `RejectedExecutionException`, you can gracefully clean up. With an `OutOfMemoryError`, your app is simply toast.

Comment: This is true. Valid point. So would the same apply to the `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` and its unbounded queue? Is the fact that it has no capacity limit an oversight since it won't throw any exception before running out of memory? Or is there some difference between its `ArrayDeque` and `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`'s `LinkedBlockingQueue` that allows it to handle more queued tasks?

Comment: "Is the fact that it has no limit an oversight since it won't throw any exception before running out of memory?" -- as I mentioned earlier (while we were writing simultaneous comments), my best guess is that they left it alone as part of a backwards compatibility decision. I don't know of any magic about its queue that somehow avoids it causing your app to run out of memory.

Comment: Backwards compatibility would have been my thought as well, although strange that the limited `Executor` is the older of the two. `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` was added without a limit. And `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`'s limit was increased by 12x later after it was no longer the default. Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Curious, what would be your preferred more modern `AsyncTask` replacement?

Comment: Well, long-term, coroutines may well be the answer. I haven't tried creating zillions of them like you have, so I'm not certain what you're running into there. Coroutines have a general-purpose feel to them, akin to `AsyncTask` ("do this work on that thread, then do this other work on this thread, #kthxbye"). RxJava is the 800-pound gorilla, and it does have a lot going for it, though the learning curve is steep. Depending on your use case, a thread pool updating a `MutableLiveData` might work and be fairly simple.

Comment: Great suggestions. We have utilized RxJava in our app, but too often I've found it to be just that, 750 pounds too much for the task it's meant to solve. Coroutines definitely seems like the way to go, but I'll need to dig into it some more to figure out how it can be optimized to launch many tasks in parallel. All the examples I've seen are launching parallel tasks from within the same suspending function scope. So it could be a matter of launching a coroutine higher in the call stack before the parallel operations.